# Which papers discuss classification or clustering of source code according to programming language?

Tags: classification, clustering, references, text-mining

My specific problem is to separate a huge archive of files containing source code and sometimes including embedded languages (apart from the main language).

Comment: I don't know of any literature myself, but this should be fairly easy using default text classification techniques like multinomial naive Bayes.

Comment: You can't "cluster according to programming language". That is classification, not clustering. Other than that, what have you tried yet? It should be fairly straightforward. Any programming language has some specific constructs that are invalid in other languages, so you should easily get a reasonable classification rate. **try it**.

Comment: We've already tried K-means using keyword frequency as features. Also tried language agnostic features like indentation level, whitespace distribution, etc. We couldn't beat a rule based classifier that took us some time and prior knowledge about the codebase.

Comment: @Plumenator As Anony-Mousse has said, every language has its own specific constructs the lexical analyzer of the corresponding compiler would look for. I cannot imagine that a rule system based on that can be outperformed by an approach not using this domain knowledge. [Lexical Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David Binkley provides a literature review summarizing current work done in the field of (semi-) automated analysis of source code. He discusses many recent papers which might point you in the right direction of your particular question.

Alternatively, Ugurel et al. (2002) develope machine learning methods to automatically classify archived source code. Overall it is difficult to direct you to more specific papers given the amount of information provided in the question and the size of this literature which has been rapidly expanding over the past twenty years. I hope the above literature review or the Ugurel paper will get you somewhere.

**References**
- [Binkley, D. (2007) "Source Code Analysis: a road map"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1254713)
- [Ugurel, S. et al. (2002) "What's the code? Automatic Classification of Source Code Archives"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.110.8302)

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at "Whats's the code" already. The survey paper is new, thanks again!